# Mailto address seems to be encoded

Tags: mailto

I found a mailto link, I want to copy the address and paste into Gmail, but the address is `00000161-c34c-d3fa-abfd-dffd89fd0000#a#anon#d#playbill.com`.  The final # seems to be in place of an @, but the rest of it seems like an encoding I've never seen before.  Can anyone tell me what this is?

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: The first part is formatted as/like a [UUID also called GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format)

Comment: @Blender http://www.playbill.com/job/title-of-show/00000161-c34c-d3fa-abfd-dffd89fd0000?q=&category=Performer&date=&state=&paid=on&union=off&intern=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code, the encoding method is quite clear:

```
<a class="jobs-email" href = "mailto:00000161-c34c-d3fa-abfd-dffd89fd0000#a#anon#d#playbill.com" onclick = "this.href=this.href.replace(/#a#/,'&#64;').replace(/#d#/,'&#46;')" data-cms-ai="0"> 00000161-c34c-d3fa-abfd-dffd89fd0000... </a>
```

Specifically:

```
   .replace(/#a#/,'&#64;').replace(/#d#/,'&#46;')
//                  @                       .
```

Thus, the email is:

```
00000161-c34c-d3fa-abfd-dffd89fd0000@anon.playbill.com
```